# css override in same page

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I tried to find an answer but nothing...

I have a small application that loads in to other websites inside a `div` tag. This `div` has a specific id like -> "myAppHere"

Now, all the html is inside this `div`, but as I can see my elements are affected by each site own css rules.

Is there a way to cancel all the other sites `css` rules?

something like:

```
#myAppHere *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    etc....
}
```

because the above sample code doesn't work well.

Comment: The question is very vague and does not specify any concrete example. From the comments, it seems that your are including content from external sites *and* your page is included in other sites. Or maybe *or*. No specific example of what is going on was given.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply add:

```
 #myAppHere * {
             ...
 }
```

cause general rules are overwritten by more specyfic rules. You didn't say in what way app is loaded in that div(is it inner frame, plain HTML etc.) so it's hard to find a solution.

What you can do(assuming it's just extra HTML added to your `#myAppHere` element) is to check CSS styles set to each element(using e.g. Firebug) and write your on rules in your CSS file, which are more specyfic.

Answer (score 2):

That's a scary requirement you have there.

You can try adding !important to the css rules, like so:

```
#myAppHere *{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    etc....
}
```

but even this won't override some elements that have a style attribute with !important in the rules, such as when this happens:

```
<div id="myAppHere">
    <div style="margin: 20px !important;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

You may be able to go into the other website's source with javascript, and strip out all style and class attributes... that's probably the only way to be sure. Something like this, if you're using jquery with your javascript:

```
$("#myAppHere *").removeAttr("style");
$("#myAppHere *").removeAttr("class");
```

Careful about removing those class attributes though, because it means that if you want to style it yourself, you won't have any classes to work with. You could add new classes in afterwards with more javascript though.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but  dont want to put important at the start as there many other css rules after it.  look at this site, they have a small toolbar in the bottom that is loaded from outside: http://mome.co.il/

Comment: just edited my answer a bit to explain the javascript needed. think itll work?

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a complete HTML document inside a `div` element, the result has invalid markup in a manner that seriously messes things up. In particular, if the inner document has any `style` element, it will in practice be taken as applying to the page as a whole.

The solution is to stop doing that (and first consider whether you can legally do such things at all – it would normally constitute copyright violation). Technically, you would need to remove or rewrite much of the content of the document being embedded (there is no simple way to deal with CSS code in them or linked from them, for example), or to use an `iframe` element (or `frame` or `object` element) to embed a page as “autonomous” (so it will be displayed in an independent sub-window).

Comment: I dont add a complete html page, only html content inside a div, and of course I load another css files to the page

Comment: @TzookBarNoy, if you only add html content, why does the question say “my elements are affected by each site own css rules”?

Comment: I mean that my html is loaded on many other sites, and are affected by each site differently because of his css rules. something like this: http://www.meebo.com/websites/

Comment: if it's loaded on many other sites, it's unfortunate that it comes with its own styling. is there a way to get the source site to remove its styling for these elements?

Comment: unfornately no, but there several "plugins" that do this:  meebo.com, mome.co.il, etc.  thanks again for your time!